# how to access a method when extending classes

Tags: php, oop

I am working on some custom code in https://github.com/Westie/OUTRAGEbot and, not being very familiar with OO stuff, I'm running into a problem.

I am trying to access a method (`writeToLog`) that I defined in a file called Logger/Default.php from another file in the Script folder. From other examples I can see throughout the code, I should just be able to use `$this->writeToLog`, but nothing happens when I do that. Accessing the method from Logger/Default.php works and I have the files loading in the proper order, so I'm lost. I've also tried to `print_r $this`, use `parent::`, etc. I know it's probably something simple due to my lack of understanding of object oriented code, but I'm at the wall at this point.

Per request, here is a copy of the code:

```
class Logger extends Script
{
    public function writeToLog($folder=NULL, $logFile, $message)
    {
        if(empty($logFile) || empty($message))
        {
            error_log('No log file or message passed to logging class', 0, ROOT.'.logs/error.log');
            return;
        }

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $folder = (strlen($folder) > 0) ? "/".str_replace("#", "", $folder) : "";
        $logFilePath = ROOT."/logs".$folder;

        if(!file_exists($logFilePath)){ mkdir($logFilePath, 0775, true); $this->writeToLog(NULL, 'general.log', "$logFilePath does not exist, creating!"); }

        $fullLogFile = $logFilePath."/".$logFile;

        $message = "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."]".$message."\n";
        error_log($message, 3, $fullLogFile);
    }
}
```

And in the new script that loads after this one:

```
class NewScriptName extends Script {
    public function onChannelMessage($sChannel, $sNickname, $sMessage)
    {
        // Log the message to a log on the server
        $this->writeToLog($sChannel, "chat_log.log", "$sNickname: $sMessage");
    } 
}
```

Comment: "nothing happens" usually means you have no proper error reporting enabled. You should get error messages when doing something invalid!

Comment: Can you post a "not" working example or your code itself. Did you extend your class of the Logger class? Is the function public? protected? private? Please mind @kingkero comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, added in a code sample. Also, I made sure logging is on for cli scripts but I'm not seeing anything logged there when I try to use the call $this->writeToLog. I would have expected an error or something, too, but nothing

Comment: `Logging` extends `Script` and `NewScriptName` extends script. This is the equivalent of class B extending class A and class C extending class A. However, you're trying to access a function in class B from class C. There's no relation tieing these classes together. You'd have to extend `Logging` or instantiate the class with the `NewScriptName` class to have access to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Logger` extends `Script` and `NewScriptName` extends `Script`. `NewScriptName` does not extend `Logger` though. You're trying to access a function that doesn't exist in the parent class `Script` but in a sibling class `Logger`. There's no relation tying these classes together. You'd have to extend `Logger` or instantiate the class within the `NewScriptName` class to have access to that function. This concept is called inheritance.

Just like children inherit traits from their parents, a class that extends another class has access to the parent class's `public` and `protected` properties and methods. However, inheritance is a one-way street. A parent does not inherit traits from their child. Likewise, the parent class will not have access to the extended (child) class's functions or properties (even if they're `protected` or `public`).

```
Logger -> extends -> Script
- Logger can access all public/protected properties of Script
- Logger can access all public/protected methods of Script
- Logger can access the writeToLog method but Script can not

NewScriptName -> extends -> Script
- NewScriptName can access all public/protected properties of Script
- NewScriptName can access all public/protected methods of Script
- NewScriptName has no knowledge of Logger
```

**Method 1:**

There are two ways to solve this problem. Class `NewScriptName` can extend class `Logger` like so:

```
class NewScriptName extends Logger {
    ...
}
```

This creates the following inheritance chain:

```
Script -> Logger -> NewScriptName
```

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, you can create a local instance of `Logger` within `NewScriptName` when you instantiate the class via a `__construct()` function:

```
class NewScriptName extends Script {

    private $logger;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->logger = new Logger();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I want this logging method to be available, I'm going to have to add it in one of the main files then if I understand you properly. Thanks, I'm slowly wrapping my head around the concepts.

Comment: You can either add it to a main file or instantiate the class and assign it to a global variable like `$Logger`. Then you should be able to access it from anywhere. It's a lot to wrap you head around.